# Why does my fragment fill the screen qua height? - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I've got a layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="<headerClass>"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_body"
        android:layout_below="@id/fragment_header"
        android:layout_above="@+id/fragment_banner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="<bodyClass>"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@id/fragment_banner"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="<BannerClass>"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Notice that the first fragment has `"wrap_content"` as param for the layout_height.

This fragment is defined qua layout as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/headerWrapper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/header_background">

        // stuff here...

    </RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see the height is set to `40dp`.

Yet, the header takes the full height of the screen. I am not sure why. I was looking at the layoutInflater class, but since I am unfamiliar with it I cannot see any problems with that. I use this line to inflate my fragment:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_header, container, false);
```

Why is it showing this behavior and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix it by putting every fragment in its own `LinearLayout` and giving the first a height of 40dp. I don't think this is the best solution, but it's all I could come up with.